# Building API using PHP, having Class as model

Tags: php, api, rest, oop

I'm trying to build a PHP API. So far I've implemented the model of the API using a class called API, having all the methods for adding/removing/updating etc. I want to make an API, so that e.g.:

example.com/post/add/data...

Turns into a request, which calls the proper methods of the model. I just have no idea about how to turn URL/URI's into method calls of the model class.

Comment: Have a look at the routing part of the Codeigniter source. It doesn't exactly that. Basically just parsing `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: I actually wanted to do something very much along of what CodeIgniter does, just had no idea how they implemented it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try comming up with scenarios:
1. If you get a post request type then you must add a product for ex
2. If the script doesn't deceive a POST params it wants to get atuff (json format for ex)
3.etc
Implement based on your needs basically.

A usefull example here:http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-http-and-rest--net-16340